# iPhone - lot of noise in audio file

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am writing raw audio bytes from two files into a new wav file to combine the two files. The resultant file which is created has the contents of both the audio clips but there is also a lot of noise in the file.

Can someone point me to a good example which shows how to write raw audio bytes to a file? Here's the basic logic that I am following

```
SInt32 leftSample1 = ReadSampleFromFile1(music_iter1);
leftSample1 = (SInt32)((float) leftSample1 * 0.7071); //to avoid clipping

SInt32 leftStereoSample2 = ReadLeftSample(music_iter2);
leftStereoSample2 += leftSample1;
if (leftStereoSample2 > 32767)
leftStereoSample2 = 32767;
else if (leftStereoSample2 < -32768
leftStereoSample2 = -32768;
// write leftStereoSample2 to the file
//do the same as left sample to right sample also

++music_iter2;
++music_iter1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have recorded a .wav file, i want to remove the background noise from that .wav file.How can i do that? please help me.. struggling for a week.

Comment: I don't want to remove the background noise. Can I disable noise cancellation in iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many times are these returning true?

```
if (leftStereoSample2 > 32767)
leftStereoSample2 = 32767;
else if (leftStereoSample2 < -32768
leftStereoSample2 = -32768;
```

just because you are not clipping, (because you are forcing it not to) does not mean you wont get artifacts (distortion) etc when you truncate the waves like that. i would see how often that was happening.

core audio has mixers. smart people have written code to deal with this kind of stuff already, so we dont have to :) MultiChannelMixer is one that does stereo mixing. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests for 65535 and -65536 are incorrect (would need 17 bits).
Try 32767 and -32768.

Comment: Did so. Still getting the same results. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Editing the question. I still get the noise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the line of code to "prevent clipping" is actually doing it's job; wouldn't you need to effectively turn down *both* streams before joining them?

Try combining two much, much quieter files.  And instead of 0.7071 on both files, try 0.5.  Or just use MultiChannelMixer, as suggested by Aran.